# Dealing with heavy-tailed residuals and clustered-like relationship

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, residuals, kurtosis

I have two financial time-series (daily log returns) and used the OLS (ordinary least squares) to fit a linear regression model. We can see that the scatterplot of two time-series shows points in a cluster, and the residuals have fat tails.

I would conclude that linear regression is not the best model here, however I am unsure on what other approach I could take in this case. Perhaps a non-linear approach would work better?

**Daily Log-Returns for two financial products:**
[image: Daily Log-Returns for two financial products]

[image]

[image]

Comment: In the top graph, what are the axes? The horizontal axis does not look like time, so what does it measure?

Comment: @Dave ah yes, sorry. The axes are daily log-returns (for financial instruments).

Comment: So horizontal is log-return for Microsoft and y is log-return for Oracle (for instance) with no regard for time?

Comment: @ they have same time, so each log return is for the same time for both companies. Now we don't care about time anymore, we only cared about that in data preprocessing. You can view it now as a DataFrame with index 1 to 5000 (should be around 5000 points), and a column for log returns of microsoft, and another column for log return of oracle.

Comment: Two possibilities I see are (i) quantile regression, and (ii) regression where you assume heavy tailed conditional distributions (eg, in the t distribution family). Each has its pros and cons.